# Defining $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, lo.logic, model-theory, definability

It was proved by Poonen that $\mathbb{Z}$ is definable in the structure $(\mathbb{Q}, +, \cdot, 0, 1)$ using $\forall \exists$ formula. Koenigsmann has shown that $\mathbb{Z}$ is in fact definable by universal formula. What is the simplest geometric interpretation of these results?

EDIT: It is important to note, as Joel says, that the first result in this direction was that of Julia Robinson in 1948 ([Definability and decision problems in arithmetic](https://doi.org/10.2307/2266510)).
The references for the latest results are: *[Defining $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$](http://dx.doi.org/10.4007/annals.2016.183.1.2)* (Koenigsmann's
 paper, [arXiv version](http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.3424)), and *[Characterizing integers among rational numbers with a universal-existential formula](https://doi.org/10.1353/ajm.0.0057)* (Poonen's paper, [arXiv version](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0703907)).

Thank you

Comment: Do you have a reference for these results? (without knowing how this is proved, it will be difficult to give a geometric interpretation)

Comment: See this question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/19840/how-do-we-recognize-an-integer-inside-the-rationals
@Guillaume: Here is a link to Poonen's paper lifted directly from above www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/ae.pdf

Comment: Probably it should be mentioned in the question that the first known definition of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$, very surprising at the time, was the 1948 result of Julia Robinson. Poonen's impressive result should be seen as a refinement of Robinson's theorem, lowering the complexity of the definition.

Comment: There is presumably some sort of categorical logic/topos-theoretic way to interpret what this says about integers (for instance, preservation by certain functors). And, I'm sure, classical model theoretic versions of said results.

Comment: Which language does this refer to? The language of ring theory? This should be added to the question, right?

Comment: Can someone comment on the reason these results are considered difficult, and were published in the Annals? Naively speaking, apparently using the ring structure it should be easy to characterize the multiplicative unit, then express natural numbers as those that are sums thereof, and using the ring structure introduce the negative integers as well. Is the difficulty getting so few quantifiers?

Comment: @MikhailKatz "then express natural numbers as those that are sums thereof" -- that's not a first-order characterization.

Comment: For example, the integers are not definable in the real field, since the latter has a decidable theory.